# What are the advantages of a trekking bike versus a touring bike?

Tags: touring, touring-bikes, bikepacking

I have been travelling on a trekking bike for some time now. When I bought it back in 2020, the salesman said that trekking bikes are the better touring bikes. Now a friend wants to buy a bike for touring and I realised that there are touring bikes like the [Patria](https://www.patria.net/produkt/terra-legendaeres-reiserad/).

I don't understand what the advantages and disadvantages are compared to a Cube trekking bike, for example.

Comment: You should probably give an example or two of what you understand by "trekking bike". Terminology doesn't always travel well between countries or even manufacturers

Comment: I agree. I would class the 'touring bike' you link to as a trekking bike; a touring bike to my mind would look like this: https://www.westbrookcycles.co.uk/surly_disc_trucker_long_distance_touring_bike_-_pea_lime_soup-19633

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no consensus on the difference between touring and trekking, and this word can be used to name two distinct categories of bikes, and depending on the country/manufacturer, one or the other can be used (the Canyon's equivalent to Cube's trekking bikes are called "Touring" for example — to take 2 German manufacturers).

Patria a good example of "long haul" touring/travel bike, they are simple but sturdy, and have "features" that are very useful for long haul touring: higher maximum admissible weight (160-180kg), mount for front racks, dynamo hubs, steel frames (sturdier, and repairing it doesn't require special equipment and skills — beyond what workshops doing welding regularly have), some have also mounts for spare spokes, and very good quality components. They may also feature components that may not appear fancy (quality mechanical disc brakes instead of hydraulic for example), but the point here is that mechanical disc brakes are serviceable on the roadside (or in remote area), while hydraulics are typically not. So basically, they are designed to be ridden with full panniers in remote areas.

Then you have "trekking bikes", like the Cube Kathmandu or ...Touring, that are more general purpose utility/commuter/leisure bikes. They are generally not rated for very high weight (120kg), have front suspension (very often an heavy coil one), are built in aluminium, very upright geometry. They very often entry-level or midrange components and hydraulic disc brakes. Note that it's typically not possible to mount front racks on suspension forks. So these bikes are designed for commuting with a light load, or groceries, or for a 1-2 hours ride.

So if your plan is to have a "travel" bike, you rather need to into the "long haul" style, and the starting point to differentiate them for the leisure bikes is the maximum admissible weight, the presence of front rack (mounts), the lack of front suspension.

That being said, any bike can be used for traveling — with minor adaptations (for example, for a "leisure trekking", probably stem, saddle, handle bar, tires), even if some are suited for that than other. If you travel for example in Europe on routes and you plan to sleep in hotels, the "leisure kind" (probably with bar-ends though) can be perfectly suited. If you intend to cross developing countries with 40kg of luggage, you might however appreciate a more sturdy bike with a steel frame. Features like suspension add weight and bring some additional failure points, so are not necessarily an advantage.

Comment: I would not say that repairing steel is easy. But a halfway decent welder can probably do a good enough job to allow you to continue your journey.